# 'module' object is not callable (Python3)

Tags: python, linux, file, ubuntu, module

I've been trying to create this code to analyze the words from the text and classify how many times the words have frequented in the text based on the years.
After creating a code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import morphemes as mf
import index_terms as idt

###############################################################################
def count_yr(counter, filename, index, size):
    '''
    counter: dictionary (key: word, value: frequency list)
    filename : file for analyzing words
    index : index for year 2000->0, 2001->1, ...
    size : total number of years
    '''
    word_count = {}
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        lst = idt(mf(file))
        for word in lst:
            counter[word] = [0]*size
        for word in lst:
            if word in counter:
                counter[word][index] += 1
            else:
                counter[word][index] = 1
    return counter







###############################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print( "[Usage]", sys.argv[0], "in-file(s)", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit()

    counter = {}

    for i, filename in enumerate(sys.argv[1:]):
        count_year( counter, filename, i, len(sys.argv[1:]))

    while True:
        query = input('Please type the word you are looking for (type "exit" to exit): ')

        if query == "exit":
            break
        
        if query in counter:
            print(counter[query])
        else:
            print("No Result")
```

It seems like `"TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"` pops up.
I have created morphemes.py and index_terms.py, and they do work well.
I don't have any idea how to fix it. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What do you expect calling *the modules* ``index_terms`` and ``morphemes`` to do? Did you mean to ``from index_terms import idt`` and ``from morphemes import mf`` perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I have mistaken this for something else! Thank you for pointing them out!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how morphemes.py and index_terms.py are structured, I assume you need to import some callable from those modules rather than trying to call the module itself, on the line `lst = idt(mf(file))`.

I.e.

```
from morphemes import SomeCallableYouNeed as mf
from index_terms import SomeOtherCallableYouNeed as idt
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much! I found the problem!